# How to convert Bitmap into a Frame?

Tags: android, bitmap, ocr, android-vision

Currently I'm working on a android program using Mobile Vision. I am using the "TextRecognizer" class and one of the methods is .detect(Frame frame). Right now I have a image I want to input into it, however, the image is the file type "Bitmap". I have tried to convert it to "Frame" by casting it but that hasn't worked. If anyone has any suggesting it would be much appreciated.

Comment: There is no `TextRecognizer` class in the Android API. Which library are you using?

Comment: I am using the Google Play Services Mobile Vision API @Henry

Comment: @Henry   com.google.android.gms.vision.text in Google Play Services Mobile Vision API

Answer (score 6):

Use the `setBitmap` method in the [`Frame.Builder`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/vision/Frame.Builder#setBitmap) class:

```
Frame outputFrame = new Frame.Builder().setBitmap(myBitmap).build();
```